# Rails naming convention for model that holds averages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

I have an application that tracks game statistics for a person, and can do various things with the averages (like rank people by average points, etc.).

Instead of constantly calling `SELECT AVG(points) FROM game_statistics GROUP BY person_id WHERE person_id = 1;`, I created an averages table that calculates and stores this any time the `game_statistics` for a person is updated.

My question is what to call this 'averages' table/model.  I could call it PersonAverages but that breaks the Rails convention of having model names be singular, and forces me to write things like:

```
class Person
  has_one :person_averages, foreign_key: "person_id", class_name: "PersonAverages"
end
```

Is there a better naming convention for this scenario, when the each table row itself can be considered a plural (ie. each row holds the person's *averages* not just a single *average*?

Comment: Still it is recommended to use singular i.e PersonAverage in this case as it will avoid confusion while querying database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work for you or if 3 hours later you still haven't decided but if your big issue is the naming convention then you could always name the table PersonGameAnalysis unless this would stray too far from saying that its the averages for the player in which case you may end up having to just bite the bullet and name the class as singular anyways.